# JavaScript error selecting only one radio button and working fine for i.e 7 but now for i.e. 9 throwing error

Tags: internet-explorer

I have javascript function which is called from datagrid about selecting only one radio button  and working fine for IE 7 but now for IE 9 throwing error
Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'getElementsByTagName'
Please suggest 
how to fix it

```
function SelectSingleRadioButton(gridViewId) {
   var grid = document.getElementById(gridViewId);
   var RadioButtonObj = window.event.srcElement;
   for (i = 0; i < grid.rows.length; i++) {
      var tr = grid.rows[i];
      var td = tr.childNodes[0];
      var items = tr.childNodes[0].getElementsByTagName("input") // the point where error is occuring
      for (j = 0; j < items.length; j++) {
         if (items[j].type == "radio") {
            if (RadioButtonObj.id == items[j].id) {
                items[j].checked = true;
            }
            else {
                items[j].checked = false;
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This bug was introduced by the recent optimizations to the clone() method.

As the variables `elem` and `clone` both can be DocumentFragments it's not safe to call getElementsByTagName on them. Because according to the specification DocumentFragements don't implement this method. The reason older IE versions don't trip over this is that they implement this method on DocumentFragments too although they shouldn't. IE9 seems to have fixed this (becoming more spec following) and removed the method and now breaks when hitting this branch.

A possible fix would be to check if `elem/clone are nodeType === 11` then check if `elem/clone.getElementsByTagName` is available, if yes use it. If no resort to `elem/clone.querySelectorAll("*")`. This should be fine as older IE versions have `getElementsByTagName` and newer versions have `querySelectorAll`.

So you can use `getElementsByTagName` for older versions of IE(IE<9) and `querySelectorAll` for IE 9.

Comment: Thanks for insight but I am afraid this solution doesn't seems to be working.